# Are the last few digits of the daily closing stock market index random?

Tags: random-generation

**(Edited to replace tenth of a degree temperature with stock index).**

I'm not sure if this is the best StackExchange site to post this question, but here goes...

I want to do a shortest straw type of lottery over email with a small group of people. My idea is make them guess the last digit of a stock market index at closing time of a given day.

For example, Alice guesses 3, and Bob guesses 7. The closing DOW index is 21,849, so Bob is closer and wins the lottery. Both Alice and Bob can check the DOW index for themselves, so there's no possible way I could have manipulated the generated number.

When determining distance to the last DOW digit, I would make the digit 9 wrap around to 0 (a circle of digits from 0 to 9).

In the case of Alice and Bob's guesses being equally-distant to the DOW digit, there would be a runoff draw using a different stock market index.

Are there any flaws to this method that could give an unfair advantage to the participants?

Is there a similar online source of daily generated random numbers?

Comment: Have you studied the *actual* distribution of digits for the noon temperatures?  If it is not consistent with a uniform distribution (and independent of all other data), then people familiar with the data will have an advantage in guessing.  There are many reasons to suppose the actual distribution could be non-uniform or--even if uniform--could still be predictable. For instance, if the underlying instrument actually reads in Fahrenheit and that is converted to Celsius, then the tenths digit will *not* be uniformly distributed conditional on the *units* digit of the temperature.

Comment: @whuber, no I have not studied the actual distribution. That's a good suggestion. I was hoping someone out there already did such an analysis, but know that I think about it, the temperature measurement hardware could be somehow biased differently between reporting stations.

Comment: Folks, I'm going to change the question to using the stock market index instead. Please hold off answering for a bit...

Comment: The analysis has to be specific to your weather station, because the distribution will depend on the instrumentation, the climate, and even the habits of the meteorologist.  For instance, in a climate where the 11 am temperature is typically very close to the 12 noon temperature, one could gain an advantage from using the 11 am reading in guessing the noon temperature. There will be comparable considerations for the "stock market"--whatever that might mean. If an individual stock, it will depend on typical bids and asks; if an index, it will depend on the weights and stocks that comprise it.

Comment: Why not just use an actual pseudo-random number generator? Ask each participant for a guess between 0 and 100 and a seed value. Sum all the participants' seed values, and use that as your seed input. Clean, reproducible, can't be manipulated, and definitively random.

Comment: @NuclearWang, the participants will undoubtedly keep their seed values secret from one another, so that would work. Thanks! The only problem is that the participants are not technical and would not understand what "seed" means. They might not trust me with the result. But that's a psychological problem and not a mathematical one as far as my question is concerned.

Comment: Look at the data.  During the last 10 years, people betting on the units digits 0-4 in the DJIA closing price would have won about 4% more often than other people.  This could be a fluke,  but the trend was noticeable by around 2012, strongly accelerated in 2016, and has continued through yesterday.  The risk of using *any* such data is that they might have subtle forms of non-randomness that could be exploited by those who happen to discover them. That's why we use random number generators.

Comment: @EmileCormier If trust is an issue, you could use an easily accessible online RNG tool. Any of the participants could go to the site, input the seed, and get exactly the same result you did. As for collusion between participants, sharing seeds with one another won't help unless you can get everyone's seed and the final sum.

Comment: @whuber, if you provided a source for the people betting of the DJIA unit digits 0-4, then I think your last comment would be a good answer to my question.

Comment: Any source ought to do.  I downloaded ten years of closing data at http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/dow-jones-industrial-average/.  But what is your question really about?  Is it about randomness of low-significance digits in economic and natural data, or is it about how to run a fair email lottery?

Comment: My question is about the randomness the low-significant digits in stock market indices. Running a fair email lottery is just background information on why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Possibly relevant -- Benford's law also implies non-uniformity for digits after the first. I don't think it would imply the size of difference whuber mentions though.